# Managed Package Upgrade fails due to sObject Describe failure

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, describesobject

After adding some features to our managed package, our attempts to upgrade the package in a production org is failing with a generic error:

> Your requested install failed. Please try this again.
>
> None of the data or setup information in your salesforce.com organization should have been affected by this error.
>
> If this error persists, contact salesforce.com Support through your normal channels and reference number: xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx(-xxxxxxxx)

Installing to a new org is fine. Salesforce Support was able to pull this from their logs:

> PackageInstallException: 00D80000000bMSR: Multiple install problems encountered [null: Variable does not exist: isAdmin: ReceiverController: Variable does not exist: isAdmin, null: Unknown property ReceiverController.isAdmin: Receiver: Unknown property ReceiverController.isAdmin]

The exception points a finger at `ReceiverController.isAdmin` which the Visualforce page **Receiver** can't find. Here's the code for that property:

```
public Boolean isAdmin {
    get {
        return Schema.SObjectType.Receiver_Link__c.isCreateable() &&
               Schema.SObjectType.Receiver_Link__c.isUpdateable() &&
               Schema.SObjectType.Receiver_Component__c.isCreateable() &&
               Schema.SObjectType.Receiver_Component__c.isUpdateable() &&
               Schema.SObjectType.Receiver_Join__c.isUpdateable();
    }
}
```

and the **Receiver.page** markup that calls it:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10">
  <c:SetupMenu isAdmin="{!isAdmin}" />
</div>
```

and the **SetupMenu.component** it calls:

```
<apex:component layout="none">
  <apex:attribute name="isAdmin" type="String"
                  description="Does the current user have administrative privileges?" />

  <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!isAdmin}" layout="block">

    // ... pure HTML code that builds a menu

  </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>
```

My guess is that the calls to check object-level permissions are returning `null`. But, why does checking object-level permissions fail? And why is the failure limited to upgrades and not installs? (We reproduced this in two orgs - clean install passes, upgrading from previous version fails.)

`isAdmin` was introduced in this version and no changes have been made to package objects/fields.

Any ideas?

Comment: We have in the past hit managed package upgrade problems where the compilation appears to be using the "before upgrade" version of one class (say class A) when compiling the "after upgrade" version of another class (say class B). This may or may not be the type of problem you are seeing. Working with Salesforce support is one solution to that. A work-around (that may or may not be practical depending on how many installs you have) is to make the change in two steps: add the feature to class A then upgrade, then add the feature to class B and upgrade.

Comment: That may have been the case @Keithc. We upgraded a test org in two steps, then the issue somehow resolved itself.